# FCM: Can We Send the 2 Types of Notifications and to Open Different Activities in Android App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am implementing FCM notifications using cloud functions. In a single app I want to send 2 notifications and whenever the notification is received then the app should open with a different activity.

- Suppose `A` is a sender who sends the notification to `B`(where B is the receiver).

  ***Here it successfully sends the notification and whenever the user clicks on the notification it goes to desired Intent***
- Now, Whenever `B` needs to send the notification to `A`

> ***I am receiving the notification in an app but when I click on the notification it is going to the above notification Intent page.But I need to redirect to other Intent with data  ***

Any suggestions in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use

```
"android":{
   "notification"{
     "click_action":"OPEN_ACTIVITY_1"
   }
 }
```

and then in android app

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: When I use these Method it is not opening any class.

Comment: This will only work if the app is in the background. If it is in the foreground you will need to implement an extension of FirebaseMessagingService and handle it manually.

Comment: IN FirebaseMessagingService I have already one intent and I passing data into that class . It is successfully happening . Now the problem is I need to send the different msg and whenevr user clicks on notification it should moves to different class

Comment: Im not sure what you want to achieve. If you send notification to app, then it should be visible on device. After click user is moved to some activity. If you send another notification with another `click_action` it should moved user to another activity.

Comment: My problem is I am not receiving the notification to app . But In firebase console it shows successfully sent the notification

Comment: You don't receive any notification? Or just the second one?

Comment: I am not receiving the 2 nd notification

Comment: Is your app is in background when you wait for 2nd notification?

Comment: No it is in foreground

Comment: Do I need to call 2 OnMessageReceived methods in FirebaseMessage Service class

Comment: If it is in foreground you should manually handle receiving push via FirebaseMessagingService. There is no need fo second `OnMessageReceived` (there is only one allowed in java), so you should try to log received message.

Comment: public class FcmListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.i(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }
    }
}

Comment: I didnot understand what you said can u answer what you are saying

Answer (score 0):

If you have problem with receiving notification in app you should log every push output:

```
public class FcmListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Message received");
        // Not getting messages here? See why this may be: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#fcm-android-background
        Log.i(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Message notification: " + remoteMessage.getNotification());
        }
    }
}
```

It will only works if app is in foreground. `When your app is in the background, notification messages are displayed in the system tray, and onMessageReceived is not called` - https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#fcm-android-background

Comment: I think this class will be called after getting notification into app

Comment: Why I am not getting the notification always for 2 nd notification. I am receiving the notification for sometimes . I cannot understand why